# How Can I debug a C program on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gcc

I am writing a C language program on Linux and compiling it using GCC.

I also use a Make file.

I want to **debug** my program. I don't want to debug a single file, I want to debug the whole program.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 34):

Compile your code with the -g flag, and then use the gdb debugger. Documentation for gdb is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/), but in essence:

```
gcc -g -o prog myfile.c another.c
```

and then:

```
gdb prog
```

If you want a user-friendly GUI for gdb, take a look at [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) or [Insight](http://sourceware.org/insight/).

Comment: There's also a graphical interface for gdb named ddd that can be useful if you're having a hard time with getting used to gdb.

Comment: +1 just to add - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588853/the-community-driven-gdb-primer

Comment: i have large no of .c file.
according to you i have to include them all.
is there any shortest way.

Comment: @ambika Just ad the -g to the CFLAGS macro in your makefile

Comment: Don't forget -Wall option and making it compile clean.

Comment: What is "prog"? There is no mention at all anywhere in the internet of that.

Answer (score 7):

I guess that you are building from the command line.

You might want to consider an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), such as KDevelop or Eclipse, etc (hint - Eclipse ... ECLPISE ... E C L I PS E).

Use an IDE to edit your code, refactor your code, examine your code - class tree, click a variable, class or function to jump to declaration, etc, etc

And - of course - to debug:

- run your code in the IDE
- set breakpoints to stop at particular lines
- or just step through, a line at a time
- examine the call stack to see how you go there
- examine the current values of variables, to understand your problem
- change the values of those variables and run to see what happens
- and more, more, more

p.s as wasatz mentioned- [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) is great - for visualizing the contents of arrays/matrices, and - imo - especially if you have linked lists

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb-based simple and useful GUI "Nemiver". It can debug your whole module comprising many source files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [cgdb](https://cgdb.github.io/)

> cgdb is a lightweight curses (terminal-based) interface to the GNU Debugger (GDB). In addition to the standard gdb console, cgdb provides a split screen view that displays the source code as it executes. The keyboard interface is modeled after vim, so vim users should feel at home using cgdb.

<sup>[github repository](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb)</sup>