# debugging of a c program in linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

i am working in c language and i have to debug my code as i want to see the behavior of my program.

i tried these command in my linux terminal:

```
    gcc readFile.c
    gdb a.out
    b main
    run
    next
```

below is my code file

```
   void main()
   {
          struct voter v[10];   
          FILE* fin;
          fin=fopen("voters.txt","r");
          if(fin == NULL) {
               perror("Error opening file");
               return(-1);
          }
          char buffer[2000];
          char arr[10][100];
          int i=0;
          while(fgets(buffer,2000,fin)!=NULL)
               strcpy(arr[i++],buffer);        
          fclose(fin);
          char del[2]="/";
          char * token;
          token=strtok(arr[0],del);
          i=0;
          while(1)
          {
               strcpy(v[i].name,token);

               token = strtok(NULL, del);

               strcpy(v[i].id,token);

               printf("%s\t%s\n",v[i].name,v[i].id);

               token=strtok(arr[i+1],del);

               if(token==NULL)
                    break;
           }

     }
```

after trying the above commands the programs runs completey to end to the file. what i was expecting that it should run next line just after main().
I don't have any idea what to do to debug my program.
Also it is not any break point on any line like this

```
    break 22
```

but to no avail. so i'm struck in it that how to debug my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590931/how-to-debug-a-c-program)

Comment: that does not solve my problem it still asks use file command. i already used that method

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbols? Add `-ggdb` to your compile command.

Comment: No i did not try that i compiled my code using -g flag

Comment: Can you share you compile command. Do you get any warnings/errors ?. On gcc, code does not compile (void main tries to return -1).

Comment: debugger and compiler version totally incompatible maybe some ABI change in between? Which versions of gcc and gdb you are using?

Comment: yes @dash-o there were some warnings, but they were stopping code to compile. also my problem was solved using -ggdb flag, thanks

Comment: Without a working source, it will be hard to provide good advice. Consider updating answer to compile without errors/warnings. Consider sharing first few lines of voter.txt

Comment: voters.txt contain "Muhammad Yousuf/43304-2042545-5
Atif Aslam/43344-6052684-2
Shoaib Malik/43224-5662735-4"