# using a function to calculate water bill in c

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to write a program that uses a function to calculate a water bill. It reads the information about water usage from a file, then calculates the water bill after tax.

This is the file:

```
g 5000
B 1250
M 50
```

This is what the output should be:

```
Type  Water usage  Cost including tax($)
g     5000              194.30
B        1250              93.89
Wrong user type
```

This is my output:

```
Type  Water usage  Cost including taxWrong user type.
g     5000          0.000000
B     1250          18.750750
Wrong user type.
```

I'm not sure if the problem lies in my formula or something else. There's obviously a problem with the if else statement in the function since it keeps printing "Wrong user type" where it shouldn't.

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double water_billcalculation(char user_type, double water_use, double bft, double at);

int main(void) {
    FILE* water;
    water = fopen("water_usage.txt", "r");

    char user_type;
    int cf;
    double bft = 0, at = 0, water_use = 0;

    printf("Type  Water usage  Cost including tax");

    while (fscanf(water, "%c%d ", &user_type, &cf) != EOF) {
        //water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use, bft, at);
        printf("%c     %d          %lf\n", user_type, cf, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use, bft, at));
    }

    return(0);
}

double water_billcalculation(char user_type, double water_use, double bft, double at) {
    if (user_type == 'G') { 
        bft = (water_use * 0.035) + 3.75;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'B') { 
        bft = (water_use * .0553) + 17.25;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'R') { 
        if (water_use <= 400) {
            bft = (water_use * .04) + 13.5;
            at = bft + (bft * .087);
        }
        else if (water_use > 400 && water_use <= 700) {
            bft = (water_use * .062) + 13.5;
            at = bft + (bft * .087);
            
        }
        else {
            bft = (water_use * .12) + 13.5;
            at = bft + (bft * .087);
        }
    }
    else { 
        printf("Wrong user type.\n");
    }
    return(at);
}
```

Comment: Your if clause covers `G`, `B`, and `R`.  Your input data is `g`, `B`, and `M`.  Two of the 3 types are invalid.

Comment: `while (fscanf(water, "%c%d ", &user_type, &cf) != EOF)` ==> `while (fscanf(water, " %c%d", &user_type, &cf) == 2)` moves the space  before `%c` and changes the test (edit as Barmar).

Comment: In the scanf format string, put the space before `%c`, not at the end.

Comment: Why do you pass `at` and `bft` as parameters to the function? It doesn't use the parameters, it always replaces them. They should be local variables in the function, not parameters.

Comment: You are not passing the input value `cf` to the calculation function. You are passing `water_use` which is `0`.

Comment: BTW, "Wrong user type" feels very much like an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr.  `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid user type: %c\n", user_type);`

Comment: If you use `fscanf` like that, you *should* call `ferror` after the loop to check for a potential error state that you need to warn the end user about.

Answer (score 4):

## The problem

You're "reading" your file in a wrong way. Change this line:

```c
    while (fscanf(water, "%c%d ", &user_type, &cf) != EOF) {
```

to this (notice the difference in the second argument of `fsanf`):

```c
    while (fscanf(water, " %c%d", &user_type, &cf) == 2) {
```

Also your `water_billcalculation` is wrong: You're looking after the user_type `G`, `B` and `R` according to your code, but you're actually looking after `g`, `B` and `M`!
So you'd need to change this part:

```c
    if (user_type == 'G') { 
        bft = (water_use * 0.035) + 3.75;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'B') { 
        bft = (water_use * .0553) + 17.25;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'R') {
```

to this:

```c
    if (user_type == 'g') { 
        bft = (water_use * 0.035) + 3.75;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'B') { 
        bft = (water_use * .0553) + 17.25;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    } else if (user_type == 'M') {
```

After this, you'll get the following output:

```c
Type  Water usage  Cost including taxg     5000          4.076250
B     1250          18.750750
M     50          14.674500
```

I'm a little bit unsure, if this is your desired output, because according to your post which says, that you'd like to have *this* output:

```
Type  Water usage  Cost including tax($)

g     5000              194.30

B        1250              93.89
 
Wrong user type
```

makes me thinking that:

- You actually don't want to "parse" the type `M`. If yes, remove the `else if (user_type == 'M')` condition in the `water_billcalculation` function.
- The calculation isn't correct or I don't see another bug in my code (althought I even ran it with valgrind, which didn't complain about any invalid actions).

## Code review

Some improvement ideas came up in my mind, when I read your code. So here are some suggestions. You can skip this, if you aren't interested in them.

### Check the return value after calling `fopen`!

`fopen` returns you a `FILE *` but only *IF* everything worked *fine*! So please make sure to add a lookup part:

```c
    FILE * water;
    water = fopen("water_usage.txt", "r");

    if (water == NULL) {
        // Thanks to @William Pursell for pointing out to use stderr for error messages, I forget that pretty often
        perror("Houston, we've got a problem: The file couldn't be opened :(\n");
        // or use the `exit()` function here (but you'd need to include stdlib.h)
        return 1;
    }
```

### String formatting

I'd recommend to use `\t` instead of counting your spaces. This would let you produce a better output. Also don't forget to add a `\n` if you're printing something in a new context.

In the beginning when I've got this ouptut:

```
Type  Water usage  Cost including taxg     5000          4.076250
B     1250          18.750750
M     50          14.674500
```

I was a little bit irritated first, because I didn't saw the line with the `g` type.

Change your output to the following:

```c
    printf("Type\tWater usage\tCost including tax\n");

    while (fscanf(water, "%c %d\n\n", &user_type, &cf) != EOF) {
        printf("%c\t%d\t\t%lf\n", user_type, cf, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use, bft, at));
    }
```

This gives me the following output:

```c
Type    Water usage     Cost including tax
g       5000            4.076250
B       1250            18.750750
M       50              0.000000
```

which is better to read (in my opinion).

#### (Optional) use switch-case

Your `water_billicalculation` could include a switch-case statement instead of nested if-else statements.

I'd have the written the function as follows:

```c
double water_billcalculation(char user_type, double water_use, double bft, double at) {

    switch (user_type) {
        case 'g':
            bft = (water_use * 0.035) + 3.75;
            at = bft + (bft * .087);
            break;
        case 'B':
            bft = (water_use * .0553) + 17.25;
            at = bft + (bft * .087);
            break;
        case 'M':
            if (water_use <= 400) {
                bft = (water_use * .04) + 13.5;
                at = bft + (bft * .087);
            }
            else if (water_use > 400 && water_use <= 700) {
                bft = (water_use * .062) + 13.5;
                at = bft + (bft * .087);
                
            }
            else {
                bft = (water_use * .12) + 13.5;
                at = bft + (bft * .087);
            }
            break;
        defaut:
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong user type: '%c'\n", user_type);
            break;
    }
    return at;
}
```

instead of this:

```c
    if (user_type == 'g') { 
        bft = (water_use * 0.035) + 3.75;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'B') { 
        bft = (water_use * .0553) + 17.25;
        at = bft + (bft * .087);
    }
    else if (user_type == 'M') { 
       // and so on...
```

but that's probably very individual, so see this as an opinion please.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes! I fixed your suggestions from 1 to 3 but I'm unsure what you mean with the fourth. Could you please explain it a little bit further?

Comment: Hm... I thought that we'd need the `\n` to make sure that it's parsing a line. I'll add your improvements. Thank you! Looks like that I need to write some C code again...

Comment: "need the \n to make sure that it's parsing a line" --> Yes, a `"\n"` does look for a `'\n'` (or any white-space)  yet it does more - unfortunately.  It directs scanning to continue looking for any white-space and does not return until a non-white-space is detected.

Comment: You might want to try `while (fscanf(water, "%c%d", &user_type, &cf) == 2) {`.  I suspect then you will see why `" %c%d"` is better.

Comment: I just created a gist to test it out: https://gist.github.com/TornaxO7/b2a4227bf9c9472a8f0f80f307c84144 When removing the whitespace before `%c` the program ends after the second input. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: "The file couldn't be found" is a very frustrating error message when `fopen` fails because of a permission error.  Just do: `char *path="water_usage.txt"; if( (water = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(path); ...`

Comment: Good point! I forgot this function.

Answer (score 1):

While @TornaxO7 answered your literal question, you would have been able to easily determine what the problem is by debugging your program:

[How to debug a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590931/how-to-debug-a-c-program)

Specifically,

- By stepping your program or breaking after the scan, you would have noticed what values you're getting in `user_type` and in `cf`.
- By stepping through the comparisons in `water_billcalculation()`, you would have noticed how comparisons you expected to succeed, fail - which would have led you to notice you're comparing `'g'` with `'G'`.

Additionally, or alternatively, adding some "debug-prints" or log-type printing to your program, at least while developing it, provides some of the same information even in regular runs without debugging.